# What is the difference between my code snippet from beginning javascript 5th edition and the code provided on the author's example site?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Ok I've been looking at these two snippets for a little over an hour now and I cannot work out what is different between them, I'm following the "Beginning Javascript 5th Edition" book's tutorials and have hit an obstacle on Chapter 3 exercise 1. I've typed the code to be exactly the same and yet my snippet doesn't work, it responds with the following error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list -- Line 11

My snippet is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Chapter 3, Example 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  var degFahren = parseInt(prompt("Enter the degrees Fahrenheit", 32), 10);
  var degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);    

  document.write(degFahren + "\xB0 Fahrenheit is " degCent +
    "\xB0 centigrade<br />");    

  if (degCent < 0) {
    document.write("That's below the freezing point of water");
  }
  if (degCent == 100)
    document.write("That's the boiling point of water");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the source code from the example site is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 3, Example 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var degFahren = parseInt(prompt("Enter the degrees Fahrenheit", 32), 10);
        var degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);    

        document.write(degFahren + "\xB0 Fahrenheit is " + degCent +
           "\xB0 centigrade<br />");    

        if (degCent < 0) {
            document.write("That's below the freezing point of water");
        }    

        if (degCent == 100)
            document.write("That's the boiling point of water");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain what I am missing here because to me my code should be working absolutely fine

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `+` sign in this code:

```
document.write(degFahren + "\xB0 Fahrenheit is " degCent +
    "\xB0 centigrade<br />");
```

It should be:

```
document.write(degFahren + "\xB0 Fahrenheit is " + degCent +
    "\xB0 centigrade<br />");
```

Comment: @jfriend00 help is greatly appreciated, I knew I was just being blind, unfortunately didn't have a second set of eyes handy.

Comment: @Hourglass if you have a syntax error like the above, the best way is to look in your browser's developer console (press F12 in most browsers) This will usually allow you to find syntax error quite quickly

Comment: @jasonscript - I had checked my dev console which is where I got the syntax error from, that wasn't the problem, the problem was that I was looking at the code and couldn't see the missing + sign, just simple blindness was all.

Comment: @Hourglass but the syntax error even gives you the line number!!

Comment: @jasonscript I saw the line number but at a little short of midnight after having been up for approximately 18 hours I couldn't see the code problem, also the error made no sense to me (see above exhaustion factor) as there were the correct number of ")" and the arguments all seemed ok, was just a bit of blindness